# Get number of bytes during a request

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, python-requests

In python, I'd like to recover the number of bytes during a request.

I did something like this (with requests module):

```
r = requests.get("https://google.fr/")
```

Not really this but this looks like. I'd like to know how many bytes the request requires and returns.

Thanks !!

Comment: what about ``len(r)``?

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: maybe ``len(r.text)`` then.

Comment: It returns a number like this : 129481 (bytes) is this it ?

Comment: Or it's just the number of characters

Comment: `len(r.text)` will return the number of characters.

Comment: Oh darn.. How should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in requests documentation shown here

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Be careful with your example though. python and requests in general have problems with SSL certificates. So the above

```
r=requests.get("https://google.fr/")
```

will give you

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

you could do

```
r=requests.get("https://google.fr/",verify=False)
```

which is not recommended ... but ok atleast you will get something
but you will not get a good content-length value in `r.headers` for the above site. Maybe some google specific issue.

in any case

```
len(r.content)
```

should give you the length of the bytes object if 'Content-Length' is missing

If you use http it will work

```
r=requests.get("http://google.fr")
r.headers['Content-Length']
```

You will get `'5433'` or something like that
 Instead try all kinds of request on http://httpbin.org

```
r=requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
r.headers['Content-Length']
```

you will get `256`

which is the byte size that is returned

For info about the request sent to the server you use

```
r.requests.headers
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood everything.. If I use https requests, what am I supposed to use to know the number of bytes ? 

r.headers['Content-Length'] returns a KeyError

Comment: the problem is this particular example of google.fr does not provide 'Content-Length'. Instead it has a field in r.headers called 'Transfer-Encoding' : 'chunked' which should contain the value of the byte request.

Comment: . But this is optional - See Section 3.6.1 of [https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6]. If the website chooses not to send the length by the OPTIONAL chunked parameters... then you cant use this method

Comment: just to note  - len(r.content) gives you the size of the byte object as represented in python. Not necessarily the number of bytes that were transferred. For example for the http: site compare `r.headers['Content-length']` which is 5436 with `len(r.content)` which is a much bigger number

Comment: In fact, I'm working on a project for the school, and my tutor has just explained to me that I have to get size of the byte object. So len(r.content) works in my case. But thank you very much for the time you devoted to me !! Thanks Thanks Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I found ! Just len(r.content) ^^ thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for https:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://google.fr/'

# use the 'auth' parameter to send requests with HTTP Basic Auth:
r = requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'pass'))

a = len(r.content)
print(a)
```